# Can I use keywords in Safari as Google Chrome?

Tags: safari, google-chrome

The main reason because I use Google Chrome on my Mac is its keyword feature that I can use as shortcut while I'm searching for something.

This is an example of my main keywords: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cHPX.png

This is an example of keyword feature in action: http://gfycat.com/IlliterateBiodegradableGreatargus

Is there a way to do the same on Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KeySearch](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/keysearch/) sounds like what you want. From the website:

> It uses short keywords to allow you to search any site you want, right from the toolbar.
>
> ...
>
> Just right-click on any search box and choose "Create keyword for this search." Type in a keyword and KeySearch takes care of the rest.

(I have not used it.)